# Solving a producer-consumer problem with NSData (for audio streaming)

Tags: objective-c, audio, buffer, nsoperation, producer-consumer

I am using AVAssetReader to copy PCM data from an iPod track to a buffer, which is then played with a RemoteIO audio unit. I am trying to create a separate thread for loading sound data, so that I can access and play data from the buffer while it is being loaded into.

I currently have a large NSMutableData object that eventually holds the entire song's data. Currently, I load audio data in a separate thread using NSOperation like so:

1. AVAssetReaderOutput copies, at most, 8192 bytes at a time to a CMBlockBuffer
2. Copy these bytes to a NSData object
3. Append this NSData object to a larger NSMutableData object (which eventually holds the entire song)
4. When finished, play the song by accessing each packet in the NSMutableData object

I'm trying to be able to play the song WHILE copying these bytes. I am unsure what a good way to write to and read from a file from the same time is.

A short idea I had:

1. Create and fill 3 NSData objects, each 8192 bytes in length, as buffers.
2. Start playing. When I have finished playing the first buffer, load new data into the first buffer.
3. When I have finished playing the second buffer, load new data into the second. Same for the third
4. Start playing from the first buffer again, fill the third. And so on.

Or, create one NSData object that holds 3 * 8192 PCM units, and somehow write to and read from it at the same time with two different threads.

I have my code working on two different threads right now. I append data to the array until I press play, at which point it stops (probably because the thread is blocked, but I don't know right now) and plays until it reaches the end of whatever I loaded and causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

In short, I want to find the right way to play PCM data while it is being copied, say, 8192 bytes at a time. I will probably have to do so with another thread (I am using NSOperation right now), but am unclear on how to write to and read from a buffer at the same time, preferably using some higher level Objective-C methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this exact thing.  You will definitely need to play your audio on a different thread (I am doing this with RemoteIO).  You will also need to use a circular buffer.  You probably want to look up this data structure if you aren't familiar with it as you will be using it a lot for this type of operation.  My general setup is as follows:

- LoadTrackThread starts up and starts loading data from AVAssetReader and storing it in a file as PCM.
- LoadPCMThread starts up once enough data is loaded into my PCM file and essentially loads that file into local memory for my RemoteIO thread on demand.  It does this by feeding this data into a circular buffer whenever my RemoteIO thread gets even remotely close to running out of samples.
- RemoteIO playback callback thread consumes the circular buffer frames and feeds them to the RemoteIO interface.   It also informs LoadPCMThread to wake up when it needs to start loading more samples.

This should be about all you need as far as threads.  You will need to have some sort of mutex or semaphore between the two threads to ensure you aren't trying to read your file while you are writing into it at the same time (this is bad form and will cause you to crash).  I just have both my threads set a boolean and sleep for a while until it is unset.  There is probably a more sophisticated way of doing this but it works for my purposes.

Hope that helps!